# A link to website sources in html

Tags: html, meta

I'm creating a new website from scratch. Its files (html, js, css, media) are compiled from sources, optimized, and… completely unreadable (by human). Yet, still I want it to be a free software. Right now I just created a single comment just after html tag, i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- sources and license: git://...... -->
<head …
```

but is there a way to make it more standard? Perhaps there is something like

```
<head>
  <meta sources="git://...." />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard meta tag for this. However, if you're hell bent on including one, you could do it like this:

```
<meta name="sources" content="git://....">
```

This is non-standard and validator.w3.org will not validate your code as valid HTML5. It would work without a problem though, even if it's probable that many will not notice it when looking at the source code, which seems to be your main motivation to do it.

The standard way to include that information would be to use a README.md file in the repository, considering you are publishing your code on GitHub/Bitbucket/Gitlab or the like and to include special comments at the top of script files. For example, in JavaScript:

```
/*!
 * This comment will usually not be stripped out by optimizers.
 */
```

Notice the `!`. You can include comments all you like but note that any kind of HTML optimizer/compressor/whatever and even Google PageSpeed plugins will just strip out comments as unnecessary bloat.

Additionally, it is considered good practice to actually have the published source code as human-readable as possible. Simply because there would be no reason for any developer to judge if your software would meet her requirements if he would have to unpack/deobfuscate/reindent/cleanup your code just to make heads or tails of it. It would basically defeat the purpose of open sourcing if the source to be opened is terrible.

Comment: If I understand well, the OP's question is exactly about providing a readable source while using a minimized version online, while linking to this readable source as clearly as possible.

Comment: Hence my comment about there being no standard way to link to the sources and alternatives to that.